# CSS3 Keyframes Animation for Cycling through Multiple Images

Tags: html, css

I have a series of images, like below. I would like to use a CSS3 keyframes animation to cycle through the images over and over again. I have tried to define separate keyframes animations with different, corresponding time percentages for each image that would run concurrently; however, that did not seem to work. Could someone help me out with this! Thanks.

```
<img src="bannerimages/e1.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/> 
<img src="bannerimages/Banner-C.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
<img src="bannerimages/bannerG.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
<img src="bannerimages/Banner-B.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/> 
<img src="bannerimages/f1.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
<img src="bannerimages/bannerH.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
<img src="bannerimages/Banner-D.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
<img src="bannerimages/bannerI.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
```

Comment: So what you want is an infinite slideshow?

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yWVVX/ - no HTML required... all CSS defined. For obvious reasons use a webkit browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add up on [RizJa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4138626/rizja)'s answer. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWVVX/77/) that demonstrates how you can animate background images so that they alternate. The first one goes by steps. The other has a smooth transition.

Like RizJa said: no HTML needed. Just CSS.

**Note** that you should set the last image (at 100% of the animation) to the same as the first one (at 0%). If you're going to loop through 8 images, that means you'll need to give them each a step of 12.5%.

The CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes test{
    0%{
        background-image: url('path');
    }
    20%{
        background-image: url('path');
    }
    40%{
        background-image: url('path');
    }
    60%{
        background-image: url('path');
    }
    80%{
        background-image: url('path');
    }
    100%{
        background-image: url('path');
    }
}

div{
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: test 12s infinite;
            animation: test 12s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
            animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
}
```